# Working with an ArrayList in an Action class and JSP view (Struts 1.x)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, arraylist, struts-1

I have an ArrayList of MCQs, taken in from the database. Once stored inside the list, i want to display the MCQs in my jsp view.
My first question is how i take in the values into the ArrayList. Posting my code with two ways i think i can do it, by using a Question model class(commented out), or the non-commented way.

```
public class QuestionsAction extends Action{
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
List<String> questionList=new ArrayList<String>();
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs=null;

Connection conn=DBConnection.createConnection();
stmt = conn.createStatement();

String query="SELECT * FROM questions";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next())
{   

    /*

     Question question = new Question(rs.getString("qid"), 
                                        rs.getString("question"), 
                                        rs.getString("answer1"), 
                                        rs.getString("answer2"), 
                                        rs.getString("asnwer3"), 
                                        rs.getString("answer4"), 
                                        rs.getString("correctAns"));                                        
     questionList.add(question);

     */

    questionList.add(rs.getString("qid"));
    questionList.add(rs.getString("question"));
    questionList.add(rs.getString("answer1"));
    questionList.add(rs.getString("answer2"));
    questionList.add(rs.getString("answer3"));
    questionList.add(rs.getString("answer4"));
    questionList.add(rs.getString("correctAns"));

    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("questionsList",questionList);
}

 rs.close();
 stmt.close();
 conn.close();

return mapping.findForward("success");
}
}
```

Second question is, once i have this ArrayList and i go to my questions.jsp to display these questions with their options. How do i do that, i searched and found the < logic:iterate > tag but unable to put it to use.

Whatever code my confused brain wrote in the jsp page:

```
<logic:iterate name="questionList">

    <bean:write name="??" property="question" />

    <li> <bean:write name="??" property="answer1" /> </li>      
    <li> <bean:write name="??" property="answer2" /> </li>
    <li> <bean:write name="??" property="answer3" /> </li>
    <li> <bean:write name="??" property="answer4" /> </li>


</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Do you want to display it in which html elements (combo box, table or radio list??)

Comment: Radio list! Sorry didn't specify!

Answer (score 0):

Better use a java class to map Question. e.g.

```
public class Question{
  Long qid;
  String question;
................. and so on
}
```

Now you can easily set all the values to the respective questions by creating an new object of Question and adding it to the list of Questions.

```
loop

    {
     Question question = new Question(); //use setter or constructor and use the value from resultSet
     list.add(question);
    }
```

For second part refer to this example.

http://codippa.com/how-to-iterate-over-list-of-objects-jstl/

Comment: awesome. That's the commented part of my code. Thank you. 
Now what about displaying it in my jsp view?